# Why isn't my Spring Cloud gateway route working when I set the PrefixPath and my URI

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway sitting in front of other microservices. The gateway is also used as an authentication layer. I have my gateway at localhost:9000 and my microservice I would like to direct traffic to that has the predicate path (`/api/scd/secure/**`) on localhost:8050. I would like to prefix /ms/platform to get to the actual rest endpoint that sits in my microservice (so `/ms/platform/api/scd/secure/**`). The problem I have is that even if I set my uri to localhost:8050, it is using the gateway uri as the final destination (so `localhost:9000/ms/platform/api/scd/secure/**`)

I have tried to do lots of reading on the spring cloud gateway about how the PrefixPath filter works but everything i read suggests my configuration should work.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: scd_secure
        uri: http://localhost:8500
        predicates:
        - Path=/api/scd/secure/**
        filters:
        - PrefixPath=/ms/platform
        - GatewaySecurityFilter
```

I would expect in my GatewaySecurityFilter, the exchange.getRequest uri to be `localhost:8050/ms/platform/api/scd/secure/**`, but it ends up with `localhost:9000/ms/platform/api/scd/secure/**`

Comment: You explicitly set the uri to port 9000, how would it know to go to 8050?

Comment: Try using RewritePath instead of PrefixPath. It is able to change the URI as well.

Comment: Have you considered using strip-prefix: false?

Comment: @spencergibb I apologize I mistyped, the URI is actually set to localhost:8500, see correction above. I found my problem after a little more reading, which makes sense now... i was using the GatewaySecurityFilter I added to see what the new route would look like, but the filter happens before it is passed to the uri that is defined, so I was seeing the new route (after the PrefixPath filter) but before the URI is utilized. Thanks for the quick suggestions though

Comment: My issue was really at the microservice serving up the requested resource

Comment: There's no reason that shouldn't work, can you provide a project that reproduces the problem?